# RewriteRule and the number sign “#”

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hash

I'm trying to make a friendly URL through `RewriteRule` but it keeps ignoring `#` as part of the variable value.
The line on .htaccess is as simple as this

```
RewriteRule ^key/(.+)/$ index.php?key=$1
```

and the requested URL is

```
http://www.example.com/key/c%23/
```

but I'm only getting `c` as get variable and not `c%23`.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after some digging, I managed to pull this off.

It just needs the `B` flag on RewriteRule to escape non-alphanumeric characters such as `#`

```
RewriteRule ^key/(.+)/$ index.php?key=$1 [B]
```

Comment: By the time a request gets to modrewrite a # character will typically need to have already been converted to %23.   However, the [B] option is the right option to use so that the %23 gets rewritten properly.

Answer (score 0):

`%23` is a hash symbol (`#`), so it (and anything after it) doesn't actually get parsed by mod_rewrite. The actual URL therefore is `http://www.foo.com/key/c`, without any `%23`. Other dash-codes work fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

`%23` is a hash mark (#). I'm guessing the browser is interpreting the hash as an anchor and not passing it on to the server. For instance, if you user `http://www.foo.com/key/c%20/` you'll get "c[space]".

Comment: but how can I bypass that interpretation and use `%23` just like Stack Overflow does? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)